# Can the base of a transistor not be an intrinsic?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Can the base of a transistor not be an intrinsic semiconductor. I think doing so would reduce recombination.
Please explain me what would happen in that situation. I suggest that npn transistors are used to explain this.

Comment: The "p" in NPN means that the base is p-type, not intrinsic. The "n" in PNP means that the base is n-type, not intrinsic.

Comment: i was thinking that if the base is intrinsic , then recombination would be zero

Comment: just try not thinking it as a normal forward and reverse biasing.

Comment: Im a high school student. . please tell how would it be different if i used an intrinsic in place of a p-type as a base

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: "just try not thinking it as a normal forward and reverse biasing" The physics of a junction transistor in normal operation works _because_ the collector-base junction is reverse biased and the base-emitter junction is forward biased.

Comment: @Qmechanic: the electrical engineering group tends to treat transistors as little black things with metal legs, and kicks questions about semiconductor physics here.  And -- this really is a question about solid state physics, not how to use a little black thing with metal legs in a working circuit.

Comment: @JonCuster please write these comments out as a full answer

Comment: @TimWescott . I told that because i just started out studying transistors . I think of them that way , majority charge carriers participating in diffusion.

Comment: @JonCuster and posterity will be grateful :)!

Comment: @Qmechanic Jon Custer's full answer below, even with the added zoological imagery, is pure physics!

Answer (score 2):

I will try to keep this fairly simple. Note that, under all the simple stuff, the actual physics 'under the hood' may get quite complicated (but that is for undergraduate device physics courses).

In a semiconductor, the concentration of electrons in the conduction band and holes in the valance band are in dynamic equilibrium such that the product of their concentrations is a constant. In an intrinsic semiconductor, the concentration of each is the same. Doping is a way to fix the majority concentration of electrons (n-type) or holes (p-type), and then the equilibrium concentration of the other has to decrease to keep the product constant. Note that this is exactly like the pH of water - in pure water the concentrations of H and OH are the same, adding an acid or a base perturbs one of them, forcing the other to a different value. Further note that the *product* remains constant, so if you force the equilibrium electron concentration to be 100x the intrinsic value by doping, the equilibrium hole concentration drops by a factor of 100, so it is now $10^{4}$ smaller than the electron concentration. In silicon, the intrinsic doping level is close to $10^{10}$/cm$^{3}$. So, if you have set a doping level of $10^{16}$ (not uncommon) for the majority carrier, the minority carrier concentration in equilibrium is now $10^{4}$ - really really tiny.

If a region in the semiconductor is not in equilibrium, it tries to get there. It can do this either by (1) having a free hole and free electron recombine, eliminating both, or (2) having a valance electron jump into the conduction band, creating both a free hole and a free electron. Carrier generation (number 2) occurs at a rate fixed by temperature (unless you are trying, such as solar panels), and is responsible for leakage current in diodes. The rate of recombination (number 1) depends on the product of the electron and hole combinations - they have to find each other to recombine.

Lets look at a bipolar transistor now. Lets assume that the (n-type) emitter is injecting electrons into the (p-type) base. In the base, we now have lots of electrons from the emitter, and lots of holes from the base doping. This is not an equilibrium situation, the [electron][hole] product is way too big, and recombination starts happening quite rapidly. All those electrons from the emitter are being sought after by all the holes, and they just don't get very far into the base - they don't have time to diffuse anywhere in particular. So, if the width of the base from the emitter to the collector is large enough, no electrons from the emitter make it to where they even know the collector exists - they all die through recombination.

So, how do we make the electrons from the emitter live long enough to make it to safety in the collector? We inject electrons into the base using the base current. This acts like "doping", altering the dynamic equilibrium concentrations of holes in the base. Remember, the product of the two wants to be constant, so this is actually a strong lever to pull on. We don't need to change the hole concentration by very much to increase the lifetime of the emitter electrons in the base. That increase in lifetime then means they can go further before dying, and some will make it to the collector. Increase the base current some more results in an even longer lifetime, and eventually one has tweaked the electron lifetime in the base to be long enough that all of the electrons can make it across to the collector.

How much current do you have to put into the base? Not much at all. Recall from above that, if the (p-type) base is doped to $10^{16}$, the equilibrium electron concentration is only $10^{4}$. If you can make that go 'all the way' up to $10^{5}$, not requiring many electrons, the hole concentration drops by a factor of 10, dropping the recombination rate with the emitter electrons by a factor of 10, greatly increasing the diffusion length. This is how a small base current can allow a large current to flow from the emitter to the collector - a small perturbation in carrier concentrations in the base changes the expected outcome from certain death (recombination) to certain survival (make it to the collector).

A (limited) analogy (well, all analogies are limited - you always have to know where they fail) is cats and mice. The base is full of hungry cats. The emitter sends mice into the base, hoping they make it to the collector. For lots of cats and few mice, well, the mice are toast. Now some mice start coming in through the base lead. The cats now see more mice, and are having a harder time catching them all. Some start making it to the collector since the cats can't keep up. Add more mice, and the cats get frantic trying to catch them all, start running into each other and the walls, and become ineffective, so all the mice run safely to the collector.

So, the base has to be doped at a high enough level, and be thick enough, that whatever the emitter injects into the base dies quickly enough that it doesn't make it across unless there is base current to change the lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

To make a triode, you need a current channel and a way to control the potential in the channel. The carrier density in the channel has to be low to make it possible to control the potential.

In in vacuum triode, the channel contains a low density of electrons in a vacuum. A grid inserted in the channel controls the potential. Electrons can flow between the grid wires at a rate controlled by the grid voltage.

In a bipolar transistor, the control electrode is the base, inserted into the channel between emitter and collector. It controls a low density of minority carriers, injected from the emitter. Its potential is controlled by an ohmic contact. Carriers can flow through it because the minority carrier lifetime in the semiconductors used is long compared to the transit time.

What you want is a field effect transistor. You can't practically put a control electrode in an intrinsic channel, but you can put it next to the channel, close enough to adequately control the potential. In practice, the channel isn't perfectly intrinsic, but in a MOSFET it can be as close as you can manage.