# Working of transistor

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

For the operation of the transistor, the base-emitter junction is forward-biased and the Base collector junction is reversed-biased. Due to the concentration gradient, electrons from the N side (Emitter) go towards the P side (Base). Since the base is lightly doped and thin and due to the reverse biasing of the base-collector junction(electric field exits between the base and collector), the electrons coming from the N side (Emitter) go towards the N side (Collector) without much recombining with the hole in the P region (Base).

Since we have a concentration gradient for electrons to flow from emitter to base then why do we need the base supply voltage in a transistor circuit?

Comment: Why do we need a transistor? The transistor is an amplifier, if we do not control the base current of a BJT how would the transistor know what should be amplified?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/745112/ may help

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0):

The concentration gradient is opposed by a charge density gradient. The electron donor atoms in the N emitter have a positive charge once they've given up an electron. Similarly, the electron acceptor atoms in the P base have a negative charge. At zero base bias, the diffusion of electrons into the base essentially ceases once enough have diffused to charge the emitter and base.

Positive base bias overcomes this electric field, allowing electrons to reach the base.